# jQuery loads twice on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I am using NextGen gallery plugin for my wordpress and my own script for header slider.

Header slider contains:

js/jquery.min.js
js/responsiveslides.js

I have this block of code in functions.php:

add_action('init', 'add_javascript');

```
function add_javascript() {
    // Add JQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // Add the scripts
    $js_url = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js';
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min',"$js_url/jquery.min.js");
    wp_enqueue_script('responsiveslides',"$js_url/responsiveslides.min.js");
}
```

and this in header.php:

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script>
      $(function () {
  $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
    maxwidth: 3200,
    speed: 800
  });
});
```

```
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.backToTop').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('.backToTop').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
$('.backToTop').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

I think jquery is loaded twice so now the gallery doesn't work properly. How should I put the code so both header slider and gallery will work?

Here's my website `http://193.2.241.108/wordpress/`

Answer (score 1):

You are loading jQuery twice.

```
function add_javascript() {
    // Add JQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); //<--- here

    // Add the scripts
    $js_url = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js';
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min',"$js_url/jquery.min.js"); //<--- and here
    wp_enqueue_script('responsiveslides',"$js_url/responsiveslides.min.js");
}
```

Remove one of your references to jQuery and that should fix the problem.